# Bone drivers cause random jittering

Tags: python, rigging, bones, drivers

I'm experiencing issues with bones when using my custom Python drivers for wrist deformation correction. The problem is the random jittering visible in the video: https://streamable.com/em7ue9.
The wrist bones are not animated. The only custom driver function I'm adding is the dot_product:

```
import math
import mathutils

def dot_product(ref_bone, ref_axis, pose_bone, pose_axis):
    if ref_axis.lower() == 'x':
        r_axis = ref_bone.x_axis
    elif ref_axis.lower() == 'y':
        r_axis = ref_bone.y_axis
    else:
        r_axis = ref_bone.z_axis
    
    if pose_axis.lower() == 'x':
        p_axis = pose_bone.x_axis
    elif pose_axis.lower() == 'y':
        p_axis = pose_bone.y_axis
    else:
        p_axis = pose_bone.z_axis    

    return r_axis.dot(p_axis)

bpy.app.driver_namespace["dot_product"] = dot_product
```

An example driver setup is as follows (they are all very similar):
[image: driver setup]
I'm using a rig from a different file and overriding it using library overrides - hence the greyed-out code section. This shouldn't be the problem though as jittering is also present in the original rig file.
Did anyone experience similar issues before? I'll add that my blender unit scale is set to 0.01 and I won't/can't change it back to 1.0.

Comment: I think I figured out the reason: my armature has multiple other drivers which don't always evaluate before my custom ones. Therefore, the dot product may be affected as the referenced bones are not yet in their "desired" position. Is there a way I can fix the evaluation order for my drivers?

Comment: Currently, my workaround is to (seemingly) pointlessly loop 10k times before returning the value of `dot_product`.